# Java and python integration

Tags: java, python, integration

I want to do have java <-> python bidirectional information\data\api call exchange. So far, I have come across lot of threads that ask about java\python integration. Most of them refer to jython. Here is overall structure of the bridge I am trying to build:

C++ <==boost==> python <==something(jython?)<==> java

I have couple of questions

1. The data that need to be exchanged between java and python is sometimes very complex. Has anyone come across some problems that I will refrain from exchanging data?
2. The last release of jython was May 2015. Is it still being actively supported\developed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jython is actively being developed but the problem is that the Python 3  support is pretty much dormant. You might as well use something as simple as JSON to communicate between java and Python.

Comment: Jython is probably your best bet, but you should know that it does not compile to one language or the other; it compiles to $py.class files, not pyc or class files.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Thanks. Interesting suggestion. But which protocol do I communicate over since I require calls to and fro from python and java?